# unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown (Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundExceptio)

Tags: java, android-studio

```
@Override
public void onEdittextDialogEnded(String result, String hint, EditTextDialog.Actions action) {

    if (Device.hasKitKatApi() && TextUtils.isEmpty(greatUri.getFilePath())) {
        Uri newUri = DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), greatUri.getUri(), result);
        // if everything is ok
        if (newUri != null) {
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundException (checked) is not a RuntimeException (unchecked), and you have to explicitly handle it.

If the overridden method throws `FileNotFoundException`, then you can do:

```
@Override
public void onEdittextDialogEnded(String result, String hint, EditTextDialog.Actions action)
    throws FileNotFoundException {

    if (Device.hasKitKatApi() && TextUtils.isEmpty(greatUri.getFilePath())) {
        Uri newUri = DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), greatUri.getUri(), result);
        // if everything is ok
        if (newUri != null) {
```

Otherwise surround the code with try and catch:

```
try {
    if (Device.hasKitKatApi() && TextUtils.isEmpty(greatUri.getFilePath())) {
        Uri newUri = DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), greatUri.getUri(), result);
        // if everything is ok
        if (newUri != null) {
        }
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
}
```